# .format is not a function on Intl.NumberFormat React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numberformatter

I'm trying to convert a number to a currency using the below function:

```
let currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-GB", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "GBP",
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
```

However, I am getting the above error `.format is not a function`.

I am using the function as such;

```
<tbody>
    {data.items.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item} className="text-right">
            <td className="text-left py-4 align-top text-sm">{item.description}</td>
            <td className="py-4 min-w-[100px] align-top text-sm font-bold">{currencyFormatter.format(item.price)} // ERROR HERE!</td>
            <td className="py-4 min-w-[100px] align-top text-sm">{item.quantity}</td>
            <td className="py-4 min-w-[100px] align-top text-sm font-bold">{item.price * item.quantity}</td>
        </tr>
    ))}
</tbody>
```

### Inc. Import/Export

currency.js

```
export let currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-GB", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "GBP",
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
```

page.jsx

```
import currencyFormatter from "../../../utility/currency";
```

Comment: It works perfectly well. Is the `curencyFormatter` defined inside the same component as this table?

Comment: @AniketPandey It's in a Util folder.

Comment: [Works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-leftpad-c5g5gk?file=/src/App.js). 
 Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: have you exported variable currencyFormatter from it's file and included it in the component where the table is located?

Comment: @AniketPandey I've moved it inside the file with the table and it seems to be working now? - Not sure if this is a requirement for it to be used in the same file or not?

Comment: @AniketPandey yes, it's being exported and imported correctly.

Comment: can you share the file where currencyFormatter is defined and also the import statement used.

Comment: _"yes, it's being exported and imported correctly"_: this statement isn't really supported by the evidence of this post. Have you done a little debugging to ensure that it _is_ being exported/imported properly?

Comment: @AniketPandey added import/export

Comment: You are importing it wrong. It is not a default export, you have to use `import {currency Formatter} from "../../../utility/currencyFormatter":`

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `import` statement is wrong. `CurrencyFormatter` is not a default export. You need to use named import for this.

**Utils/currencyFormatter.js**

```
export let currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-GB", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "GBP",
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
```

**component1.js**

```
import {currencyFormatter} from './utils/currencyFormatter.js';

export default function Component1(){
return(
<tbody>
    {data.items.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item} className="text-right">
            <td className="text-left py-4 align-top text-sm">{item.description}</td>
            <td className="py-4 min-w-[100px] align-top text-sm font-bold">{currencyFormatter.format(item.price)} // ERROR HERE!</td>
            <td className="py-4 min-w-[100px] align-top text-sm">{item.quantity}</td>
            <td className="py-4 min-w-[100px] align-top text-sm font-bold">{item.price * item.quantity}</td>
        </tr>
    ))}
</tbody>
)
}
```